# TinyMCE wraps my text in <p></p>. Can I avoid this?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE ([`http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)) in a .NET page.
Whenever I load a text

```
myTMCE.value=mycontent;
```

I can see that  my text gets wrapped in `<p></p>`. This is not desirable for me, so I am trying to avoid it.
Trying to initialize in

```
        <script>
            tinyMCE.init({
                force_p_newlines: true
            })

        </script>
```

did not work.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance,
m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could strip <p> tags after the fact using .NET, or alternatively, just use a plain <textarea> field for data entry if that suits what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think I'll strip the leading and trailing <p></p> but is a dirty solution.

Comment: Note that when tinyMCE initializes it will re-add the <p></p> so look at the stored code to see effectiveness of stripping, not at the code loaded by editor.

Comment: NOTICE: Not wrapping text with tags may cause some plugins not to work, such as the Directionality plugin which needs to insert its direction rule to a tag. Might matter for some non-LTR folks.

Answer (score 9):

You need to to do this :

```
<script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        forced_root_block: false,
        //some other options here
    })
</script>
```

By default TinyMCE sets as a root block. By setting this property to false you remove any wrapper for the text. The below text is from TinyMCE documentation:

> This option enables you to make sure that any non block elements or
>   text nodes are wrapped in block elements. For example
>   **something** will result in output like:
>
> **something**
>
> This option is enabled by default
>   as of 3.0a1.

If you set this option to false it will never produce P tags on enter or automatically it will instead produce BR elements and Shift+Enter will produce a P.

Note that not using P elements as root block can severely cripple the functionality of the editor.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=3720) and [the answer](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=16296#p16296) in TinyMCE forum. force_p_newline is a gecko only option (ie FF).

Comment: however afaik force_p_newlines has another pourpose.

Comment: The answer in that thread did not work for me.  Added the following to init but tinyMCE behavior did not change. apply_source_formatting : true,
   remove_linebreaks : false,
   entity_encoding : ""

Comment: Answer is not right: `force_p_newlines` has another pourpose

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE adds a whole load of tags to the text - its design goal is to create valid html from arbitrary input (including html input). If you want control over the generated html code, you're better off using another editor.

Comment: that's a pity, because tinyMCE works quite well, beside this unwanted behaviour.